# Get string with translation from Google translate

Tags: java, gson

i have faced some problem - i need to integrate Google Translate API to my project but i'm new and can't understand how to do it properly. This code is made just for example.
What i have now when i launch:few seconds for input and then program is closing.
What i want to have: i put my input and get translation in console(+ in array if possible). 
Also i made folder "libs" and added here gson-2.8.5.jar.
Thank you in advance.

```
package com.company;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.http.HttpClient;
    import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
    import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

    public class Connect {
        public void gogo() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String query = "key=AIzaSyB2HijQLlsmI1udH9ARl45oC5eAj4XfjTw"
                    +"&source=en"
                    +"&target=uk"
                    +"&q=hello";
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://www.googlepis.com/language/translate/v2?"+ query))
                    .header("Referer", "https://www.daytranslations.com/free-translation-online/")
                    .GET()
                    .build();
            String responseJson = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
                    .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                    .body();
            System.out.println(responseJson);
        }
        }
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Connect connect = new Connect();
    connect.gogo();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your request, try `"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?"` instead.

A basic way to use Gson to deserialize the API response would be:

```java
JsonParser.parseString(responseJson).getAsJsonObject()
        .get("data").getAsJsonObject()
        .get("translations").getAsJsonArray()
        .get(0).getAsJsonObject()
        .get("translatedText").getAsString();
```

Comment: ok, thank you for finding typo, dont know how i missed that. Now its working, but where should i add your code in my program ?

Comment: In your example, `System.out.println(responseJson);` prints the full JSON string. Assuming you are only interested in printing the actual translation, you can print the string from my snippet instead.